# Selecting Section line at the bottom of LiveCharts

Tags: c#, charts, livecharts

Why is it not possible to select and move a section line at the bottom?
I can only select a section line at the top. 
(see Image below)

[image: LiveCharts Image]

Answer (score 2):

The section is added to the canvas first and the path, that is drawing the line series, is added second. The section has the same z-index (0) as the path.
Z-order works like a stack when the z-index is equivalent therefore the last added item is the topmost of a group of items with the same z-index.
So in your case the line series is drawn on top of the section and blocks the selection of the section.

Setting the z-index to 1 on the axis section solves this

- XAML: `<lvc:AxisSection Panel.ZIndex="1" \>`
- Code behind: `Canvas.SetZIndex(control, index);`